# How to avoid Ant Design override existing CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, antd

I am doing a ReactJS project. At first, the project was only written in pure CSS, then I wanted to use a small Antd component for my project. I followed the instructions and imported like this into a specific ReactJS component:

```
import { Pagination } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

The issue is that my existing CSS is overridden by Ant Design. Can you please give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to import your own css file after you import your AntDesign file.

eg.

```
import { Pagination } from 'antd';

import '../ownstyle.css'
```

in you ownstyle.css

```
@import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

.ant-pagination{
  .....
}
```

Comment: I tried and it's still the same.

Comment: maybe you can try to create your own style css and put the antdesign css import file above you own styling. Then in this file only import the "import { Pagination } from 'antd';"

eg
       @import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
       
       .ant-pagination{
         ......
       }